# DevOps vs Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, bamboo, devops

I am wondering how exactly does docker fit into CI /CD .
I understand that with help of containers,  you may focus on code , rather than dependencies/environment. But once you check-in your code, you will expect tools like TeamCity, Jenkins or Bamboo to take care of integration build , integration test/unit tests and deployment to target servers ( after approvals) where you will expect same Docker container image to run the built code.
However, in all above,  Docker is nowhere in the CI/CD cycle , though it comes into play when execution happens at server. So, why do I see articles listing it as one of the things for DevOps.
I could be wrong , as I am not a DevOps guru, please enlighten !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker is just another tool available to DevOps Engineers, DevOps practitioners, or whatever you want to call them. What Docker does is it encapsulates code and code dependencies in a single unit (a container) that can be run anywhere where the Docker engine is installed. Why is this useful? For multiple reasons; but in terms of CI/CD it can help Engineers separate Configuration from Code, decrease the amount of time spent doing dependency management etc., can use it to scale (with the help of some other tools of course). The list goes on.

For example: If I had a single code repository, in my build script I could pull in environment specific dependencies to create a Container that functionally behaves the same in each environment, as I'm building from the same source repository, but it can contain a set of environment specific certificates and configuration files etc.

Another example: If you have multiple build servers, you can create a bunch of utility Docker containers that can be used in your CI/CD Pipeline to do a certain operation by pulling down a Container to do something during a stage. The only dependency on your build server now becomes Docker Engine. And you can change, add, modify, these utility containers independent of any other operation performed by another utility container.

Having said all of that, there really is a great deal you can do to utilize Docker in your CI/CD Pipelines. I think an understanding of what Docker is, and what Docker can do is more important that a "how to use Docker in your CI/CD" guide. While there are some common patterns out there, it all comes down to the problem(s) you are trying to solve, and certain patterns may not apply to a certain use case.

Answer (score 7):

Docker facilitates the notion of "configuration as code".  I can write a Dockerfile that specifies a particular base image that has all the frameworks I need, along with the custom configuration files that are checked into my repository.  I can then build that image using the Dockerfile, push it to my docker registry, then tell my target host to pull the latest image, and then run the image.  I can do all of this automatically, using target hosts that have nothing but Linux installed on them.

This is a simple scenario that illustrates how Docker can contribute to CI/CD.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is also usefull for building your applications. If you have multiple applications with different dependencies you can avoid having a lot of dependencies and conflicts on your CI machine by building everything in docker containers that have the necessary dependencies. If you need to scale in the future all you need is another machine running your CI tool (like jenkins slave), and an installation of docker.

When using microservices this is very important. One applicatio can depend on an old version of a framework while another needs the new version. With containers thats not problem.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a DevOps Enabler, Not DevOps Itself: Using Docker, developers can support new development, enhancement, and production support tasks easily. Docker containers define the exact versions of software in use, this means we can decouple a developer’s environment from the application that needs to be serviced or enhanced. 
Without Pervasive Automation, Docker Won’t Do Much for You : You can’t achieve DevOps with bad code. You must first ensure that the code being delivered is of the highest quality by automating all developer code delivery tasks, such as Unit testing, Integration testing, Automated acceptance testing (AAT), Static code analysis, code review sign offs & pull request workflow, and security analysis.
Leapfrogging to Docker without Virtualization Know-How Won’t Work : Leapfrogging as an IT strategy rarely works. More often than not new technologies bring about abstractions over existing technologies. It is true that such abstractions increase productivity, but they are not an excuse to skip the part where we must understand how a piece of technology works.
Docker is a First-Class Citizen on All Computing Platforms : This is the right time to jump on to the Docker bandwagon. For the first time ever Docker is supported on all major computing platforms in the world. There are two kinds of servers: Linux servers and Windows servers. Native Docker support for Linux existed from Day 1, since then Linux support has been optimized to the point of having access to the pint-sized. 
Agile is a Must to Achieve DevOps : DevOps is a must to achieve Agile. The point of Agile is adding and demonstrating value iteratively to all stakeholders without DevOps you likely won’t be able to demonstrate the value you’re adding to stakeholders in a timely manner. So why is Agile also a must to achieve DevOps? It takes a lot of discipline to create a stream of continuous improvement and an Agile framework like Scrum defines fundamental qualities that a team must possess to begin delivering iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Docker saves the wastage for your organization capital and resources by containerizing our application. Containers on a singe host are isolated from each other and thy uses same OS resources. This frees up RAM, CPU and storage etc. Docker makes it easy to package our application along with all the required dependencies in an image. For most of the application we have readily available base images. One can create customized base image as well. We build our own custom image by writing simple Dockerfile.  We can have this image shipped to central registry from where we can PULL it to deploy into various environments like QA, STAGE and PROD. This  All these activities can be automated by CI tools like Jenkins.
     In a CI/CD pipeline you can expect the Docker coming into picture when the build is ready. Initially CI server (Jenkins) will checkout the code from SCM in a temporary workspace where the application is built. Once you have the build artifact ready, you can package it as an image with the dependencies. Jenkins does this by executing simple docker build commands.

Answer (score 0):

Docker removes what we all know the matrix from hell problem, making the environments independent with its container technology. An open source project Docker changed the game by simplifying container workflows and this has resulted in a lot of excitement around using containers in all stages of the software delivery lifecycle, from development to production.

It is not just about containers, it involves building Docker images, managing your images and dependencies on any Docker registry, deploying to an orchestration platform, etc. and it all comes under CI/CD process.

Answer (score 0):

**DevOps** is a culture or methodology or procedure to deliver our development is very fast. **Docker** is a one of the tool in our devops culture to deploy application as container technology (use less resources to deploy our application).

Answer (score 0):

Docker just package devloper environment to run on other system so that developer need not to worry about whether there code work in there system and not work in production due to differences in environment and operating system.
It just make the code portable to other environments.